# Displaying subfiles loaded with sorted database records

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Let's say, for example, I have these tables:

USRMF(main physical file)

```
User ID   User Name  
A00001    SAMUEL
A00002    ADAM
```

USRTS

```
user id   date   time in    time out
A000001   080812 084555     104545 
A000001   080812 120800     150000
A000001   080812 170000     180000
A000001   090812 084555     104545
A000001   090812 170000     180000
A000002   080812 084555     104545 
A000002   080812 120800     150000
A000002   080812 170000     190000
A000002   090812 084555     104545
A000002   090812 170000     190000
```

where my subfile should look sort like this:

```
Option:  5-display

OPT   User ID   User Name  Date   TimeIn  TimeOut
 _    A000001   SAMUEL     090812 084555  180000
 _    A000002   ADAM       090812 084555  190000
 _    A000001   SAMUEL     080812 084555  180000
 _    A000002   ADAM       080812 084555  190000
```

*Where this subfile shows summary data per user & day:
the first time in and the last time out.  The name should be read from the other database table (USRMF), and it should be sorted by the time card date.

If the user puts option 5 on the third subfile line,
where user id:A000001 user name:samuel and date 090812,
 then the to next subfile screen will be shown.

```
OPT   User ID   User Name  Date   TimeIn  TimeOut
 _    A000001   SAMUEL     080812 084555  104545 
 _    A000001   SAMUEL     080812 120800  150000
 _    A000001   SAMUEL     080812 170000  180000
```

This subfile should list all the time in and time out for the day and person selected.

How should I do this program????????? Especially for the first subfile.?????

Answer (score 5):

## Database

First of all, any DBA will tell you, if you are creating this from scratch, don't use DDS to define your files.  In the long run, you will be better off if you define them with SQL, something like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE USERMAST
      (UserID     char(7),
       UserName   char(25)
      );
    LABEL ON TABLE  USERMAST is 'User Master Table';

    CREATE TABLE WORKPERIOD
      (UserID     char(7),
       WorkDay    date,
       StartTime  time,
       EndTime    time
      );
    LABEL ON TABLE  WORKPERIOD is 'User Work Periods';
```

Note that this is using actual data and time fields, not numeric fields. This makes it easier to manipulate as needed.  When you run SQL, you can specify your preference for date and time formats, such as *ISO, *DMY, or *EUR.  You can think of it as being stored in *ISO format, but given to you in whichever format you wish.

Whether your files (tables) have been defined in DDS or SQL, you should still use embedded SQL to read the data in your program.  At first, it may seem more complex than native I/O.  But as you learn about it, you will see it is more powerful, easier, faster, and flexible.

### Processing

The basic concept for embedding the SQL is not actually that complex.  Your program could something like this in free-format ILE RPG (assuming that is what you are using):

```
       EXEC SQL      DECLARE CURSOR c1 FOR your-select-statement;
       EXEC SQL      OPEN c1;
                     do while SQLSTATUS is ok;
       EXEC SQL        FETCH FROM c1 INTO :var1, :var2, ... ;
                       if SQLSTATUS is ok;
                         // process data
                       endif;
                     enddo;
       EXEC SQL      CLOSE c1;
```

Check for end of data, or other issues, by checking the first two characters of `SQLSTATE`.  '00' means everything is OK, '01' is a warning (probably not ok), everything else is an error.  (This is easier than using `SQLCODE`.)

You put a SELECT statement (more specifically a full-select) in your DECLARE CURSOR statement, that determines what the system will give you when you FETCH from the cursor.  The SELECT can do a lot of powerful things.  Here it will get information from both tables and summarize rows for you.  If you were only summarizing, it might look like this:

```
    SELECT userid, workday, min(starttime) as firsttime, max(endtime) as lasttime
      FROM workperiod
      GROUP BY userid, workday
```

If you were just joining data from both tables, it might look like this:

```
    SELECT u.userid, u.username, p.workday, p.starttime, p.endtime
      FROM UserMast as u
      JOIN WorkPeriod as p  on u.userid = p.userid
```

The prefered way to put these together is like this:

```
    WITH s as
    ( SELECT userid, workday, min(starttime) as firsttime, max(endtime) as lasttime
      FROM workperiod
      GROUP BY userid, workday
    )
    SELECT u.userid, u.username, s.workday, s.firsttime, p.lasttime
      FROM UserMast   as u
      JOIN WorkPeriod as p  on u.userid = s.userid
      ORDER BY workday descending, username
      FOR INPUT ONLY
```

For more information on using SQL to access the database look in the [IBM i Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/eserver/ibmi.html).  Look under Database / Reference.  For information on Display files look in the Information Center under Programming / DDS / DDS for Display files,

---

## Display File

As far as your display file goes, you will need to define at least two record formats for each subfile screen -- a subfile record format, and a subfile control record format.

The subfile record is for a row in the list.  It should have the `SFL` keyword.

The subfile control record manages the screen.  It normally contains your screen headings and column headings for the subfile.  It should have `SFLCTL(yoursubfilename)`, `SFLSIZ(subfile-rows)`, `SFLPAG(rows-per-page)`, nn `SFLDSP`, nn `SFLDSPCTL`, nn `SFLCLR`, nn `SFLEND(*MORE)`, where nn represents a conditioning indicator.  You generally want to specify that the subfile-rows are 1 more than the rows-per-page.  Also include any function key specs here.

You probably also want a record format for the bottom of the screen, to tell the user what function keys may be used.  If so, use the `OVERLAY` keyword on the subfile-control record.

### Processing

1.) Turn off `SFLDSP` and `SFLDSPCTL` to prevent them from showing on the screen for the moment.  Turn on `SFLCLR` to enable creating an empty subfile.  Now WRITE the subfile control record.

2.) Inside your loop processing rows from the database, increment the subfile record number, and WRITE a subfile record.

3.) When done filling in subfile records: Turn on `SFLDSP` and `SFLDSPCTL` so that both will be shown.  Turn off `SFLCLR` so that your subfile records are not wiped out.  Turn on `SFLEND` so that it will display "More..." at the bottom of each page, except the last.  WRITE your footing record.  EXFMT your subfile control record.  Process any function keys as applicable.

Comment: Sure, but why? In it may seem complex at first. But I reality it simplifies your programming.  Often you will find you can replace complex logic in RPG with a single statement in SQL. Take a looked at what you what you would have had to do in this program. Logic to read through multiple time rcds, summarize them, then a chain to go get the users name. Here you only have one read (fetch) per single line. You leave it to the SQL optimizer to decide the fastest way to get your result.  It will perform faster, with fewer lines to write, fewer lines to debug. Win-win all the way around.

Comment: Yes,  it is something new to learn, but you will find  SQL is used all over the place, by most databases.  Whatever you do in your career, chances are that you will find knowing SQL a valuable skill.

Comment: It is a two part answer, SQL and display files.  You are free to use one part without the other.  And the question of whether the files were created with DDS or SQL is also mostly independent from whether you use SQL or native I/O.  My answer is intended to lead a learner in the direction of what I would call "best practices", from rather long experience.  But take your pick, however you wish.  Or take a bit now, and another bit later.

Answer (score 0):

@WarrenT provided an excellent answer, and even if you don't prefer SQL you can use the general concept to load and display a subfile.  The way most of us learnt was through a very old book called the [Application Display Programming](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/books/c4157150.pdf) guide.  It hasn't changed in 15 years.  Aside from this, I strongly urge you to have a colleague show you how the rest of your group does subfile programming.  There are almost certainly style issues that you want to conform to.

Comment: Good point. Each company tends to have their own way of doing things, and there are many variations on this. Follow their standard practices wherever you can. There are common issues such as whether you manage the subfile yourself (subfile page = subfile size), or how many records do you load at a before displaying to the user.